# VHDL-parse error, unexpected GENERIC, expecting END

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I have a piece of code in vhdl:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity UartTX is


    port(clk,reset,tx_start,s_tick:in std_logic;
            datain : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            tx_done : out std_logic;
            tx:out std_logic);

    generic(DBITS : integer := 8; SB_TICK : integer := 16);

end UartTX;

architecture Behavioral of UartTX is

type tx_state is (idle,start,data,stop);

begin


end Behavioral;
```

While checking for syntax in Xilinx ISE 10.1,
the error

> parse error, unexpected GENERIC, expecting END

is coming related to the

> generic

part of entity declaration. What would be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `generic` clause must be before `port` clause, so just move the `generic` clause up inside `entity`.

Comment: An example of BNF not contained in the Syntax summary being normative, in this case in the LRM's Entity header description (e.g. IEEE Std 1076-1993, 1.1.1), _where the order is only specified in the BNF_.